# Filtering based on price

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currenting trying to filter my products with jQuery. Pricing low/high. I've successfully done this, but as soon as I click the filter, my products lose their positioning and I'm not entirely sure why. They go max width and completely ignore their bootstrap classes.

Example code below:

Click the link and you'll see what I mean. Any ideas?

```js
var ascending = false;

$('.tab-content').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function() {

  var sorted = $('.results-row').sort(function(a, b) {
    return (ascending ==
      (convertToNumber($(a).find('.price').html()) <
        convertToNumber($(b).find('.price').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
  });
  ascending = ascending ? false : true;

  $('.results').html(sorted);
});

var convertToNumber = function(value) {
  return parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="filters">
    <p>
      <a class="sortByPrice" href="#">Sort by Price</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="results">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-4">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="results-row">
          <figure class="card card-product">
            <div class="img-wrap item"><img src="http://kb4images.com/Random-Image/number-148116.html">
            </div>
            <figcaption class="info-wrap">
              <h4 class="title">Good product</h4>
              <p class="desc">Some small description goes here</p>
            </figcaption>
            <div class="bottom-wrap">
              <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right">Order Now</a>
              <div class="price-wrap h5">
                <span class="price-new price">$1280</span> <del class="price-old">$1980</del>
              </div>
              <!-- price-wrap.// -->
            </div>
            <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
          </figure>
        </div>
        <!-- col // -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="results-row">
          <figure class="card card-product">
            <div class="img-wrap item"><img src="http://kb4images.com/Random-Image/number-148116.html">
            </div>
            <figcaption class="info-wrap">
              <h4 class="title">Good product</h4>
              <p class="desc">Some small description goes here</p>
            </figcaption>
            <div class="bottom-wrap">
              <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right">Order Now</a>
              <div class="price-wrap h5">
                <span class="price-new price">$1080</span> <del class="price-old">$1980</del>
              </div>
              <!-- price-wrap.// -->
            </div>
            <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- col // -->
    </div>
    <!-- row.// -->
  </div>
</div>
<!--container.//-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, you have used wrong selectors, and replaced two divs needed by bootstrap *.container-fluid* and *.row-mb-4*:

I also changed selector for less confusing and source I called *.product* and result div with bootstrap class called *.results*:

```js
var ascending = false;

$('.tab-content').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function() {

  var sorted = $('.product').sort(function(a, b) {
    return (ascending ==
      (convertToNumber($(a).find('.price').html()) <
        convertToNumber($(b).find('.price').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
  });
  ascending = ascending ? false : true;

  $('.results').html(sorted);
});

var convertToNumber = function(value) {
  return parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="filters">
    <p>
      <a class="sortByPrice" href="#">Sort by Price</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-4 results">
      <div class="col-md-3 product">
        <div>
          <figure class="card card-product">
            <div class="img-wrap item"><img src="http://kb4images.com/Random-Image/number-148116.html">
            </div>
            <figcaption class="info-wrap">
              <h4 class="title">Good product</h4>
              <p class="desc">Some small description goes here</p>
            </figcaption>
            <div class="bottom-wrap">
              <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right">Order Now</a>
              <div class="price-wrap h5">
                <span class="price-new price">$1280</span> <del class="price-old">$1980</del>
              </div>
              <!-- price-wrap.// -->
            </div>
            <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
          </figure>
        </div>
        <!-- col // -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 product">
        <div>
          <figure class="card card-product">
            <div class="img-wrap item"><img src="http://kb4images.com/Random-Image/number-148116.html">
            </div>
            <figcaption class="info-wrap">
              <h4 class="title">Good product</h4>
              <p class="desc">Some small description goes here</p>
            </figcaption>
            <div class="bottom-wrap">
              <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right">Order Now</a>
              <div class="price-wrap h5">
                <span class="price-new price">$1080</span> <del class="price-old">$1980</del>
              </div>
              <!-- price-wrap.// -->
            </div>
            <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- col // -->
    </div>
    <!-- row.// -->
  </div>
</div>
<!--container.//-->
```

Comment: Yeah, in moment when I was writing my answer there were no solution. You're code works but I also clarify why author code didn't work and propose some improvments for less confusing. Do not be angry :)

Comment: Hey I am not :). no worries.  Giving you +1 for the improvements. But I think it is not really needed. As OP already has a class there. Anyways Happy coding bro.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$('.results-row').sort(function(a, b)
```

to

```
$('.col-md-3').sort(function(a, b)
```

Since you are sorting `results-row` I believe you are removing the `col-md-3` div (parent of .results-row) which has some css related to it.

```js
var ascending = false;

$('.tab-content').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function() {

  var sorted = $('.col-md-3').sort(function(a, b) {
    return (ascending ==
      (convertToNumber($(a).find('.price').html()) <
        convertToNumber($(b).find('.price').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
  });
  ascending = ascending ? false : true;

  $('.results').html(sorted);
});

var convertToNumber = function(value) {
  return parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="filters">
    <p>
      <a class="sortByPrice" href="#">Sort by Price</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="results">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-4">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="results-row">
          <figure class="card card-product">
            <div class="img-wrap item"><img src="http://kb4images.com/Random-Image/number-148116.html">
            </div>
            <figcaption class="info-wrap">
              <h4 class="title">Good product</h4>
              <p class="desc">Some small description goes here</p>
            </figcaption>
            <div class="bottom-wrap">
              <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right">Order Now</a>
              <div class="price-wrap h5">
                <span class="price-new price">$1280</span> <del class="price-old">$1980</del>
              </div>
              <!-- price-wrap.// -->
            </div>
            <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
          </figure>
        </div>
        <!-- col // -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="results-row">
          <figure class="card card-product">
            <div class="img-wrap item"><img src="http://kb4images.com/Random-Image/number-148116.html">
            </div>
            <figcaption class="info-wrap">
              <h4 class="title">Good product</h4>
              <p class="desc">Some small description goes here</p>
            </figcaption>
            <div class="bottom-wrap">
              <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right">Order Now</a>
              <div class="price-wrap h5">
                <span class="price-new price">$1080</span> <del class="price-old">$1980</del>
              </div>
              <!-- price-wrap.// -->
            </div>
            <!-- bottom-wrap.// -->
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- col // -->
    </div>
    <!-- row.// -->
  </div>
</div>
<!--container.//-->
```

Comment: When you downvote. Please make sure to add comment so to explain what is wrong with the code.

Comment: This code results in destroying "row mb-4", which seems undesirable.